# What were the personal tax rates in the Byzantine Empire during the 6th and 7th centuries?

Tags: economy, byzantine-empire

What were the tax rates per person in the Byzantine Empire during the 6th and 7th centuries?

My findings:

1. wikipedia: [Byzantine Economy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byzantine_economy) (has no information regarding the tax rate per person of the Byzantine Empire.)
2. [Slate article about Byzantine tax code](http://www.slate.com/articles/news_and_politics/explainer/2011/10/the_byzantine_tax_code_how_complicated_was_byzantium_anyway_.html)

Comment: Relevant: https://www.quora.com/How-high-was-taxation-in-the-Byzantine-Empire-during-the-6th-and-7th-centuries

Comment: I think this question needs more improvements. Does anyone have any suggestions to improve it?

Comment: Well, it's pretty broad... and makes the assumption that there was a single, uniform tax rate for everyone across the whole empire, which there wasn't.  [Check out the Wikipedia entry on Byzantine law, for an example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byzantine_law): `The Farmer's Laws ... peasants were organized in "communities" and collectively responsible for the payment of the total tax the "community" was liable for ... `